# BaseModel list returns tuple in Python/fastAPI/Mongo env

Tags: python, mongodb, fastapi, pydantic

I am using env with python311, pydantic, fastapi & mongod

```
return membercollection(members=await c_members.find(queryparam).to_list(1000))
```

Returns:

```
members=[membermodel(id='65b3908a77efb45072f69237', UserId='7677', MemberName='DIng DOng', Gender='M', Age=42, Age_AsOn=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 12, 0, 0), CreatedDTM=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 26, 16, 29, 7, 52000)), membermodel(id='65b51a80bb2cea5c74e1e8a6', UserId='7677', MemberName='on cloud 9', Gender='M', Age=42, Age_AsOn=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 12, 0, 0), CreatedDTM=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 27, 14, 56, 5, 763000))]
```

I want to get only the list (without initial "members=") removing "members=" from code throws error:

```
TypeError: BaseModel.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I want to check returned list and perform further operations on it however the current return format is complicated to loop and work on each attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by using - https://github.com/romis2012/pydantic-collections
it allows list of BaseModel as a class without adding additional attribute